How to catch any projection?
In case it needs to know if projection is provided, how can it be implemented?
@Component({
  template: `{{ projections().length }}`
})
class MyComponent {
  projections = contentChildren('*'); // pseudocode, '*' - fake selector
}

Is there any proper way to observe all projections despite a type?

We can just add a elementRef #test and query for this value, which will give us two values!
main.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './app/child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <app-child>
        <h1 #test>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
        <h1 #test>Learn more about Angular</h1>
    </app-child>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

child.ts
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  computed,
  contentChildren,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
  <ng-content/>
  {{ projections().length }}
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  projections = contentChildren('test');
}

Stackblitz Demo

We can also query for the inner elements, to access the inner values!
Child.ts
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  computed,
  contentChildren,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
  <ng-content/>
  {{ innerProjections().length }}
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  projections = contentChildren('test', { descendants: true });
  innerProjections = computed(() => {
    const projection: ElementRef<any> = this.projections()?.at(
      0
    ) as ElementRef<any>;
    return projection?.nativeElement?.children;
  });

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.projections());
  }
}

main.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './app/child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <app-child>
      <div #test>
        <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
        <h1>Learn more about Angular</h1>
      </div>
    </app-child>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

stackblitz demo

Thanks for the answer, but #test does not satisfy to "any projection"
